# How to dynamically label headers in Excel using numbers across columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Per screenshot below, I'd like to setup a formula in row 8 to accomplish the effect between Scenario 1 and 2 wherein I hide a column (in this case Column Banana) and therefore the numbered headings change accordingly (i.e. Column Kiwi changes from (5) to (4)).  I would've just used the Subtotal() function but it doesn't work across columns, only rows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried combining subtotal with transpose?

Comment: Use VBA or `Get & Transform` (aka `Power Query`)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld these exhibits are part of a larger report spanning multiple tabs where the columns need to be hidden are not always in the same spot.  If I had a formula, it would be easy to just hide the column in the sheet I'm on

Comment: @P.b I did and wasn't able to make it work

Comment: Unable to test (using a mobile device) : `=SUM(IF(CELL("width",$B1:B1),1,0))` maybe you need to MAP it.

Comment: @arks Should be simple with VBA to label just the visible columns.

Comment: `=SCAN(0,B9:F9,LAMBDA(a,b,a+(SUM(CELL("width",b))>0)))` this works, but needs recalculation (`F9`) each time a column is hidden, to recalculate the correct result.
vba would be a better solution, if that's allowed.

Comment: @P.b this worked!  I copied this to B8, it reads the headings in the row below it and adds the numbers.  to format them similar to my example I used ..."a-(Sum...."  Thank you!

Comment: Note that changing the hidden columns doesn't change the result until you recalculate. That's why I posted it as comment rather than answer. With VBA you can have it update live.